# running octave with netcdf package

Tags: octave, netcdf, netcdf4

I am trying to run octave in order to process netcdf files.  While I am able to currently run octave successfully I have been having a very difficult time loading the package netcdf for octave.

I have used the command:

```
pkg -forge install netcdf
```

However when I type in:

```
pkg load netcdf
test netcdf
```

I get the following error message:

```
????? netcdf source code with tests for dynamically linked function not found
```

When I do a pkg list I get the following:

```
Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
--------------+---------+-----------------------
  netcdf *|  1.0.12 | /home/jsnyder/octave/netcdf-1.0.12
  octcdf  |  1.1.10 | /home/jsnyder/octave/octcdf-1.1.10
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Does anyone have specific instructions on how to successfully install netcdf so that it will work on octave?  That includes where to get the netcdf files necessary for octave, how to successfully compile them, and then finally be able to successfully load into octave so that I can use this to process netcdf files.

Comment: I think you should explain why you had "a very difficult time loading the package netcdf for octave". There are different ways depending on your Operating system/distribution and version of GNU Octave (you've mentioned none of them so far)

Comment: netcdf seems to be a package supported by octave forge https://octave.sourceforge.io/netcdf/index.html therefore in theory all you have to do to install it is `pkg install netcdf -forge`. Is this what you tried doing? (note that once installed, to use any package you must load it first, i.e. `pkg load netcdf` )

Comment: it's `test_netcdf` NOT `test netcdf`

Answer (score 4):

These instructions have worked for me in the past:

```
sudo apt install netcdf-bin
sudo apt install liboctave-dev
sudo apt install libnetcdf-dev

in octave pkg install -forge netcdf
Then before using pkg load netcdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Clinton's reply, I will recount the steps I took to installing it here, in the hope that it sheds some more light in the process of both installing and figuring out what to install in general in these situations.

I typed

```
pkg install netcdf -forge
```

in octave. Initially it complained with `checking for nc-config... no`

To find out which package provides this command, I ran in the *linux* terminal:

```
apt-file search nc-config
```

(note that if you don't have the `apt-file` tool you might need to install it first).

The output of the `apt-file` command informed me that this file is provided by the package `libnetcdf-dev`. So I installed this.

Retrying `pkg install netcdf -forge` worked the second time, and I can load the package successfully.

I also note that the second command you're trying to run is probably `test_netcdf`, NOT `test netcdf`. The former is a command included in the netcdf package, the latter is attempting to perform unit tests using the octave built-in testing syntax.

Doing `test_netcdf` seems to work fine for me after the above steps.

Comment: I am on Centos not ubuntu and I noticed that was unable to install libnetcdf-dev or even find nc-config.  Any ideas on who to deal with said situation?

Comment: @jms1980 the equivalent to `apt-file search filename` command on rpm systems relying on `yum` package manager seems to be `yum provides filename`. You can then do `yum install packagename` for that specific package.

Comment: @jms1980 It is worth giving it a try if you only find liboctave-dev.  I vaguely (!!) remember this worked